# ImportError: No module named clr when using CPython of python.org

Tags: python, .net, clr, cpython, python.net

I'm writing C++ code which should invoke python scripts underneath.
For this purpose I use cpython of [python.org](http://www.python.org).
Some of the python scripts execute .net code with help of python for .net and when it comes to .net all this fails.
I tried to build test app to verify where it fails and found that it can't import clr module.

When I run this code it give me ImportError: No module named clr

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import clr");
```

If I go to python console and type "import clr" everything works fine.
I also checked sys.path and it contains the folder where clr.pyd located 'C:\Python27\DLLs'.
I also tried setting this path in C++ by:

```
char* path = "C:\\Python27\\dlls";
Py_Initialize();
PySys_SetArgv(1, &path);
char* phome = Py_GetPythonHome();
```

But it didn't helped. In addition I don't understand why clr module is appears as clr.pyd and not .pyc like other compiled modules.

Could someone can explain why import clr fails through CPython?
Is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 19):

To install clr, you have to install pythonnet library.

You can install pythonnet using following command.

```
 pip install pythonnet
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `PySys_SetArgv` after `Py_Initialize` appropriately to change the syspath.

Comment: Tried it but w/o any result. I updated my post with more details.

Answer (score 1):

I work behind a proxy server with multiple versions of python.
I have a bat file I update when I need a new module, or wish to update an existing one.
The first line sets the path to the version I wish to update
The bat file is run from the scripts directory.
Proxy IP with port "9.254.0.1:81"

```
SET path="C:\Programs\Python\Python3_64"
pip install --proxy="9.254.0.1:81" --upgrade pip
pip install --proxy="9.254.0.1:81" pythonnet
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is most commonly caused by having multiple Python installations that may (or may not) be part of you (Windows) *system* **PATH** variable. When you start your Powershell, it will use that PATH, depending on:

1. The order placement in the (Windows) *System* PATH.
   (Does your *Python3.7* come before *Python3.8*?)
2. If you have other Python interpreters installed, such as:
   `conda`, `miniconda3`, etc., which have their own paths.

Then when you do `pip install pythonnet`, the package will be installed in the system package location, depending on which pip you are using. Check with `pip -V`.

**For example**:
If you find your default shell to starting with `conda` *activated*, you need to do `conda deactivate` before you do your `pip install`.

```bsh
(base)  $ pip -V
pip 20.2.4 from c:\users\xxxx\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

(base)  $ conda deactivate
$ pip -V
pip 20.2.4 from c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```